# Why I cant handle exception?

Tags: python

I set proxy using

```
import os
proxy = '123.456.11.22:80'

os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy 
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy
```

Sometimes my proxy drops down (throwing ProxyError) and in this case I need change variable "proxyError". I use this code:

```
try:
    proxyError = 0
    connectFunction()
except ProxyError:
    logPrint("Connection lost. Reconnecting...")
    proxyError = 1
```

And I cant handle ProxyError because python says what "ProxyError" is uknown. I try this:

```
 try:
        proxyError = 0
        connectFunction()
    except os.ProxyError:
        logPrint("Connection lost. Reconnecting...")
        proxyError = 1
```

This dont work too. That I need to catch?

Comment: Figure out where you need to import `ProxyError` from and import it from there. It's not a standard exception. (Maybe the one from `requests.exceptions`?)

Comment: `from requests.exceptions import ProxyError` should do the trick, as long as other code is working based on `requests` module

Comment: try this `from requests.exceptions import ProxyError`

Comment: It works, but why i need use requests if I use "os" library for proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProxyError` is nothing but a class in python and the namespace rule apply to it too, so you need to either import `ProxyError` or use it where it is located.

In `requests` library exceptions for the `requests` library are created at [requests.exceptions](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/exceptions.py)

so if you want to handle exception as below:

```
try:
    proxyError = 0
    connectFunction()
except ProxyError:
    logPrint("Connection lost. Reconnecting...")
    proxyError = 1
```

you need to import exception class as below:

```
from requests.exceptions import ProxyError
```

otherwise you can handle it as below:

```
try:
    proxyError = 0
    connectFunction()
except requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
    logPrint("Connection lost. Reconnecting...")
    proxyError = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why in need a requests lib if I use standart 'os' library?

Comment: are you talking about use of `os.environ['HTTP_PROXY']` statement?

Comment: Yes, I talking about this

Comment: checkout this documentation part for it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ